# error with WHERE EXISTS mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SET @userID := 1;
SELECT 1 AS isSmoker WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SituationID 
                                     FROM usersituation 
                                    WHERE UserID=@userID
                                      AND SituationID=3);
```

SQL query:

```
 SELECT 1 AS isSmoker WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SituationID 
                                      FROM usersituation 
                                     WHERE UserID=@userID 
                                       AND SituationID=3)
```

> MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT SituationID FROM usersituation WHERE
>   UserID=@userID AND ' at line 1

This is the error I am receiving but I don't know why it happens.

The

```
SELECT SituationID FROM `usersituation` WHERE UserID=@userID AND SituationID=3
```

returns a row when used alone.

**Note:**

> The purpose of the Query is, if the subquery returns any value then
>   return one row with the value of 1 in a custom column named isSmoker

Comment: you have omit the `from` clause.

Comment: You are missing `From`

Comment: thing is I don't want to get any value from any existing column, if the subquery is true i just want to get a row of Value 1 in a column named isSmoker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you need the query to return the `True`, if the subquery returns a result.
Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
EXISTS (SELECT SituationID 
        FROM usersituation 
        WHERE UserID=@userID 
        AND SituationID=3) 
THEN '1' 
END AS isSmoker
```

Comment: no I want it to return 1 meaning TRUE, in short if the SituationID for that user is 3 then I want to return 1 so later i can use that to compare it with something else

Comment: With words " check the situation table and see if the user has a situation with ID = 3 (3 is the id for smoker) if yes return for me 1(TRUE) in a way that i can set it into a variable (this query) INTO @smoker and so i can use this var later

Comment: Updated the answer, no need to use `From` here

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @userID := 1;
SELECT 1 AS isSmoker from usersituation WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT SituationID FROM usersituation WHERE UserID=@userID AND SituationID=3);
```

You can try above code.

Here you forgot **from** keyword.

Comment: No this is not what i want, I want it to do this, if the subquery returns any value then return one row with the value of 1 in a custom column named isSmoker